# Using BeatifulSoup to drill down into specific web data point

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a basic weather website request as below:

```
import requests, bs4, lxml
url = ('https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?..')
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
```

A large  section with a class and id holds the information i'm looking for. I've pulled that out with the below

```
weather = soup.find(id='detailed-forecast-body')
```

Here's an example of `print (weather.prettify())`

```
<div class="panel-body" id="detailed-forecast-body">
 <div class="row row-odd row-forecast">
  <div class="col-sm-2 forecast-label">
   <b>
    Today
   </b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 forecast-text">
   A slight chance of showers before 9am, then a slight chance of showers and thunderstorms after 3pm.  Mostly sunny, with a high near 68. Breezy, with a north wind 8 to 13 mph increasing to 15 to 20 mph in the afternoon. Winds could gust as high as 30 mph.  Chance of precipitation is 20%.
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row row-even row-forecast">
  <div class="col-sm-2 forecast-label">
   <b>
    Tonight
   </b>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 forecast-text">
   Mostly clear, with a low around 40. North wind 9 to 14 mph becoming light and variable. Winds could gust as high as 21 mph.
```

If I want to pull the text from say, "Tonight", should i pull it from the weather object i created? OR should i work from the soup object created?

How can i create a condition to pull the text only from Tonight?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

As the text 'Tonight' contains inside the `weather` object , you can just use the `weather` object.

`tonight_text = weather.find('div',{'class':'forecast-label'}).text`